# Passing an argument to the Django ModelForm clean method

Tags: django, modelform

I am trying to pass an argument to the clean method of my ModelForm so that I can perform some extra validation on some data.

In my views.py file, I have:

```
page_data = page_form.cleaned_data(foo="bar")
```

In my clean_url method, I have:

```
def clean_url(self, **kwargs):
    url = self.cleaned_data['url']

    if kwargs['foo'] == url:
        query = FlatPage.objects.filter(url=url)
        if query.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(("This url is already being used by the '%s' page.") % (query[0].title))

    return url
```

I keep getting a KeyError for `foo`. I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake here, as I've passed kwarg variables before, but never to a clean method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key lies in passing the paramaters through the ModelForm's init method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.url = kwargs.pop('url', None)
    super(FlatPageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This variable can then be referenced in the clean method by calling self.url

```
def clean_url(self):
    url = self.cleaned_data['url']
    if self.url == url:
         #do something
    else:
         #do something else
```

Answer (score 4):

When using Class Based Views, you can use `get_form_kwargs` to pass the variable from the view to your form and then to you clean method:

In your view:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(MyCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'url': self.kwargs['url']})  # or wherever the url parameter is coming from
    return kwargs
```

In your form:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.url = kwargs.pop('url', None)
    super(FlatPageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then reference `self.url` in your `clean()` method.